# COBOL expression as index in table array

Tags: arrays, indexing, cobol

just a short quick question.
How do you index an expression into a COBOL array?
For example, if my index `k=1`, I would like to do the following to find an element of `k=2`

```
element(k+1)
```

Unfortunately this is not acceptable in COBOL and I would like to know if there is any alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think that won't work, as long as you put it in a Cobol statement.

```
   ID DIVISION. 
   PROGRAM-ID. SUBMOD. 
   DATA DIVISION. 
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01  A-NICELY-NAMED-TABLE. 
       05  FILLER OCCURS 2 TIMES. 
           10 A-NICELY-NAMED-ENTRY  PIC X. 
   01  ANOTHER-PIECE-OF-DATA        PIC X VALUE SPACE. 
   01  A-NICELY-NAMED-SUBSCRIPT BINARY 
                                    PIC 9(4). 
   LINKAGE SECTION. 
   01  L-INPUT                      PIC X(4). 
   01  L-TO-HEX                     PIC BXBXBXBX. 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING L-INPUT L-TO-HEX. 
       MOVE "A"                     TO A-NICELY-NAMED-ENTRY ( 1 )
       MOVE "B"                     TO A-NICELY-NAMED-ENTRY ( 2 )
       MOVE 1                       TO A-NICELY-NAMED-SUBSCRIPT 
       IF A-NICELY-NAMED-ENTRY ( A-NICELY-NAMED-SUBSCRIPT + 1 ) 
           EQUAL TO "B" 
           MOVE A-NICELY-NAMED-ENTRY 
            ( A-NICELY-NAMED-SUBSCRIPT + 1 ) 
                                    TO ANOTHER-PIECE-OF-DATA 
       END-IF 
       DISPLAY ">" ANOTHER-PIECE-OF-DATA "<" 


       GOBACK 
       .
```

Output is:

```
>B<
```

With reference to your comment, it is not a "strictness" thing by any means. It is that "+ 1" is one thing, a "relative subscript", and "+1" is something else, it is a second subscript.

Depending on your compiler, you may be able to code:

```
MOVE ELEMENT(k++1) ...
```

You may have to put up with some moaning from the compiler, and I suppose in some it may not work. It would, however, but a horrible way to write Cobol.

I'd suggest not using names like ELEMENT. Too likely at some point in the future to appear as a "reserved word" for Cobol. Don't be shorthand. Use good names, use effective spacings. It'll help you understand your program a little later, and will help anyone else who has to look at it.

Comment: actually, you are right. It was just a matter of having space in the parameter. Overlooked the strictness of the language there. Thanks!

Comment: Also, although I'm not sure, if you use a "true" index (as in INDEXED BY...) I think this wont work.  Haven't tried it, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: It works also with INDEXED BY. You can't "compress" in the same ugly way if you want "negative" relative subscripting, as the compiler will think it is part of a badly-formed data-name. "Subscripting" means using either a "subscript" or an "index". "Relative subscripting" works for subscripting, so for a subscript or an index.